# Does Exchange 2007 license allow Exchange 2003 to be installed and used?

Tags: exchange-2007, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Does having Exchange 2007 license allow me to install Exchange 2003 and use it instead? (for example if system is 32 bit only and Exchange 2007 is x64 so can't be installed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> STANDARD LICENSING DISCLAIMER:
>
> While SF can give you a decent idea, and more often than not a very good answer, the best place to ask these types of questions is to ask you licensing representative from Microsoft.

I believe that if you bought the license via one of the open license programs you have downgrade rights (possibly only applicable with Software Assurance as well)

The [Downgrade Rights](http://oem.microsoft.com/script/contentpage.aspx?PageID=552836#server) Page may contain useful information (I didn't read it through too thouroughly)

Comment: +1 for "ask your representative". MS licensing is unfortunately ridiculously complicated.

Comment: I wouldn't call MS Licensing "ridiculously complicated" but it is an acquired taste. At least they've started standardizing the different products by line. Now if they'd just make it the same for the 3 different ways of buying licenses, we'd be set.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you get it. If you just buy Exchange 2007, so long as the previous version is supported, you can use previous versions. Note that your licenses must match. If you licensed 2007 server, you can't use 2003 CALs, even if you're install 2003. You do have to call MS and get keys to install 2003 though, and that'll be a fun call.

If you get Exchange through Small Business Server (or some packaged deal like it) then no.